# Access primary keys with multiple instances of databases being recombined

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

**What is the most effective Primary Key (PK) in Access (2013) when multiple instances of a backend database may be in use, for which the instances will occasionally be imported into a main database?**

As an example, say database A (DBA), database B (DBB), and database C (DBC) are being used; occasionally DBB and DBC will be "imported" into DBA and then new instances of DBB and DBC created by duplicating the newly recombined DBA.

So say for table "tblIncidents" an auto-number PK is used for each incident. When I split off DBB or DBC from DBA, the last PK is 100. As incidents are added to each database, PK 101 is different in DBA versus DBB versus DBC. When importing DBB or DBC into DBA, the PK cannot be relied upon since there will be multiple instances of the PK with differing records.

For this specific issue, it is not possible to use just one database because multiple organizations will be using the database and some of the organizations do not allow access to outside servers.

I apologize if there is an obvious answer to this question, but I've done a significant amount of Googling to no avail.

Comment: Have you investigated using "Replication ID" AutoNumbers? They are mentioned brielfy [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoNumber), and are still available in Access 2013. (Screenshot from Access 2010 [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NsBh7.png).)

Comment: That's the simple and reliable solution. If you only mix one or few tables, another is to add a field to the relevant tables named, say, SourceId, set this to a unique fixed value for each database, and change the primary key to a compound key composed by SourceId and the existing ID.

Answer (score 0):

Replication ID's are a horrible, terrible solution to this problem. As the once well known Michael Kaplan commented in response to a similar question:

> other gotchas? DLookup problems, Form/Subform problems, combo/listbox
>      issues, and more? What will it take to convince you?  KB article entitled
>
> "Access: GUID primary keys will kill you in your sleep"
>
> or something like that?
>
> BTW -- a PK involving a DATE field, which is a double and thus subject to
>       floating point issues, is also a bad choice. I would suggest serious design
>       thought and perhaps a good look at the NATURAL keys?

from "microsoft.public.access.modulesdaovba", but it appears that you need to login to google to view the usenet archive.

Here is his article about it http://www.trigeminal.com/usenet/usenet011.asp?1033

Comment: For the record, that article was written fifteen (15) years ago.